# How to create or save a PDF with printing/editing restrictions without using Adobe?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint, adobe-acrobat

I saved a Powerpoint as a pdf in Office 2007 but I don't see any options to add print restrictions or edit restrictions to it.

I don't have Adobe either, so I'm wondering if there is any alternative way to add restrictions to a pdf.

I know there are tools to remove document restrictions, but can they do they opposite?  Is there any freeware or websites available that can add restrictions to my pdf I created?

I found a [website](http://www.en.conv2pdf.com/) that looked promising but it didn't end up working (The upload didn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change restrictions for an already created PDF, you can use PDF-XChange Viewer. You can download this for free and open the PDF you want to modify. Go to File > Document Properties.
Go to Security Section of the Properties window and change Security method from No Security to Password Security. [image: Security Settings in PDF-XChange Viewer]

You can use PrimoPDF software.... This will allow you to print any document/webpage any thing that can be printed to a PDF, you can also set Security options like password etc

[image: PrimoPDF Security Options]

Comment: PDF-XChange Viewer worked great! They even have a portable version.

Answer (score 0):

Foxit has a 30 day trial.
http://www.foxitsoftware.com/PDF_Editor/protect-sign.php the document encryption section looks promising.